# How can I change screen's resolution?

Tags: resolution

As you can see in the title, I'd like to increase my screen's resolution(which dicreased on its own!), but when going to displays, screen can not be recognized and it's unknown. It may be too easy to do, but I'm new here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the 'Additional drivers' app and see if you can install drivers for your graphical card that are a little bit more adapted.

Anyway, please edit your question to indicate what monitor you use, what graphical card you have and which version of Ubuntu you are running, the latest being Ubuntu 11.10. Please also specify what you mean by "decreased on its own": between what moment and what moment did that change appear and what have you done in between? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, by the way!

Comment: Here's what happened!I shut down my computer and then turn it on and the letters were so big like I was blind or something.Then I got to the displays and realised that resolution was 1024x768 while previous it was 1280x720. I tried to icrease it but it wasn't accepting my screen so I shut down the computer again and then open it. And guess what?Now it recognized it!Anyway, for the record I have Ubuntu 11.10 and my monitor is Fjitsu Siemens GmbH 20'' ass for the graphic card it's on the motherboard and it's kind of difficult for me to check it!

Comment: In case anything like that happens again I'll have additional drivers in mind! I'm new here, but I try for the best! Thanks